# How to specify dependencies on other projects with .NET CLI?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

It is common to break a large solution is multiple projects for a question of organization of the code base and this was easily done in the earlier versions of the .NET Framework from inside Visual Studio.

How the same can be done with .NET CLI? Suppose we have the following simplified scenario for example:

```
- Solution Folder
    - global.json
    - src
        - LibProject
        - ConsoleProject
```

Suppose now that the `ConsoleProject` depends on the `LibProject`. Intuitively I belive that this means that in the `ConsoleProject` the `project.json` will have to contain a `dependencies` section like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "LibProject": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

But if we do this, when we try to restore the dependencies for the `ConsoleProject` or when we try to build it we can't do it. When we try to restore we get the message

> Unable to resolve 'LibProject (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.

I understand the reason. When restoring, NuGet is trying to find this as a package on the specified feeds on the `NuGet.config`. But it shouldn't do this, it should use the one on the sibling folder.

In the previous versions of .NET Core, we would add the reference through VS and then, if we would try to build the `ConsoleProject`, VS would first build `LibProject` and use the corresponding DLL.

How the same kind of thing is done here? How do we reference another project in the same solution and how do we restore/build/run with the .NET CLI considering this kind of dependency?

Comment: Any luck if you do `"LibProject": { "target": "project" }`?

Comment: In newer versions of the dotnet cli that uses `csproj` format, you can run `dotnet add reference ../MyProject/MyProject.csproj`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference

Answer (score 4):

After you define the projects the solution have on the global.json file you can just reference them on the project.json by name without a specific version.

Example:

global.json

```
{
    "projects":[
        "ConsoleProject",
        "LibProject"
    ]
}
```

ConsoleProject/project.json

```
{
    "dependencies":{
        "LibProject":"",
    }
}
```

You can find a better example in here: http://forums.dotnetfoundation.org/t/referencing-another-project-in-net-core/1298/2

Or in this repository: https://github.com/cartermp/dnx-apps/tree/master/multiple-projects

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this didn't work. Perhaps it worked before with DNX, but with .NET CLI it is not working. In truth this approach seems strange, because we are running `dotnet restore` from inside the folder `src/ConsoleProject` while `global.json` is sitting side to the `src` folder, so that `dotnet` toolchain can't see it. Anyway, the problem I'm facing is not really with specifying a version, but making the `dotnet restore` pick `LibProject` from the sibling folder, instead of looking on the NuGet feeds.

Comment: It looks that the global.json file is not required anymore. Which version of dot net cli are you using? Here's an issue similar to yours and seems to be working. https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/966#issuecomment-174206475

Comment: It is the version 1.0.0-rc2-002476. Anyway, I made it work now, it was a typo on the dependencies that was causing the problem. Anyway: there are some details I've found out - for using the `dotnet` toolchain, the `global.json` file isn't really needed, but it is required for Omnisharp work right in VS Code. Also, we can indeed reference the version of the project, like `"LibProject": "1.0.0-*"` that also works fine. Thanks for the aid.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation on writing libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-use-multiple-projects), the new correct way of specifying a dependency on another project in the solution is:

```
{
    "dependencies":{
        "AwesomeLibrary.Core": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "target": "project"
        }
    }
}
```

The `target: project` bit tells NuGet that it shouldn't look in a package source.

This assumes you have the following directory structure for your solution:

```
AwesomeLibrary
|__global.json
|__/src
   |__/AwesomeLibrary.Core
      |__Source Files
      |__project.json
   |__/AwesomeLibrary.Other
      |__Source Files
      |__project.json
/test
   (... etc)
```

With a `global.json` file like:

```
{
    "projects":["src", "test"]
}
```